# mssql windows credential on pdo over iis-php

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, pdo, sqlsrv

I need login on MsSQL through Windows credential got by PDO running on IIS/PHP. I can't reach this one I'm just obtaining:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myuser'
```

To do this I'm using a fake MsSQL account with his credentials hided inside the PHP code. I'm able to login on my Active Directory server by the way, after this I also need to login on a MsSQL server in my corporate network.

This is the constructor for the connection in my PHP class:

```
public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) {
 $this->dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=".$host.
 ";Database=".$dbname.
 ";TransactionIsolation=".PDO::SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED,
 $user,$pass);
}
```

I get user and pass from POST packets, I can't use single sign on because this is a middleware with json answers also for smartphone devices without an active Windows login instance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible in current version. When you pass username and password, sqlsrv extension will be always use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication. Look carefuly on the following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628159(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I thought it was not possible with official tools, I'm also looking for a workaround

Comment: I really don't understand to your use case. Your users should know a database login?!  How many accounts do you want to have? Each user from AD doesn't have automaticaly access to sql server, you still need add an account credentials to database and set the permission to it. You can configure IIS to run after your domain credentials and it should be used also by sqlsrv extension. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: My users just know their AD account, the application verify if their credential are valid then access to a DB MsSQL. Once is connected and logged, a second query verify their enabling using a such of serial number.

Comment: My trouble is access to the DB MsSQL with AD account without use a local one. Now just to work I'm using a local account, but I can't keep it.

Comment: To better clarify this is the code of this middleware:
https://nopaste.me/view/3bf4978c

Comment: Server specification are: Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7, PHP 5.6.20, MsSQL 2008 R2

Comment: Ok. You are authenticating users against LDAP server. It's good and automatic process. But I still don't understand why each user should have own account at SQL server and even client should passed connection settings over HTTP request. I've never seen that. Anyway, there is (in my opinion) no workaround without SSO and impersionation. You should consider rethink you architecture.

Comment: Users of my corporate network are grouped by rights, for example the right to log on certain MsSQL databases.  Once you log into my application, you must be in the proper group to get the flag wich can open connections with the database. You can be in the proper group also, but you can't receive new data in this case I remove your devideID from your profile. There are three check: 
1) have a valid AD account; 
2) be in the proper group (based on AD); 
3) have the permission in my application with your deviceID

Comment: There is a such of redundant table, with the replication of few profiles that comes from AD logins, with just name surname userID (same user of AD) deviceID and an enable flag. I check your account logged from AD with the right to query a such database, into my redundant table. If you get the acknowledgement you can receive data from another middleware in your smartphone, to make it short.

Comment: Well, I still think there is no workaround for your use case. You just simply can't use domain login in you situation (at least not for each user depending on credentials they provided by hand). I can't help you more.